# Sensible way to populate a formGroup's formControls from an object

Tags: angular

I want to use a form page I have for both creating and viewing/editing requests. If editing the request, I have an object with the data that I'd like to set the formControls' values to to populate the request on the form for the user.

I can set all the values like below, but there are a lot of other properties of a formControl that this doesn't affect, like `touched` and `valid`. Is there a good or right-er way to populate the form than what I tried? (below, where `entity` is the source object)

```
let formKeys = Object.keys(this.userForm.controls);
for (let i=0;i<formKeys.length;i++) {
    this.userForm.controls[formKeys[i]]._value = entity[formKeys[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setValue()` seems to work to populate the data on the page, as well as set the formControl to `VALID` if the data passes validation.

`let formKeys = Object.keys(this.userForm.controls);
 for (let i=0;i<formKeys.length;i++) {
    this.userForm.controls[formKeys[i]].setValue(entity[formKeys[i]]);
 }`